# Angular: Getting data from Firestore. HTML not updating with realtime data until clicked

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a small webapp with Angular.

I query a firestore database and get data back. Once I receive the data I have to display it. However the area of the app displaying the data doesn't refresh until I click somewhere else (or on something else) in the app.

I'm using an Observable for the data and I have a subscriber which gets triggered when the data is updated (console.log) -- however the UI is not.

I've tried `ChangeDetectorRef` and `detectChanges` and not loading the html until the data is ready with an `*ngIf`

I have a subscriber method which triggers correctly

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log("inited component.");
  obs$.subscribe(value => {
    console.log("Data List Update: (" + value.length + ") items in our dataset");
  })
}
```

and in my component html file I have:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of obs$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
</div>
```

I should see the html list populate immediately when the subscribe function is called, but this doesn't happen until it's refreshed by angular by another event.

Comment: Marking to close this as Off-Topic as the issue is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're just misunderstanding how it works.

You need to assisign the value you get so the html know what's inside. Try this:

```
obs$.subscribe(value => {
  this.items = value;
  console.log("Data List Update: (" + value.length + ") items in our dataset");
})

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
</div>
```